# Как исправить ? На граничных значениях неверные сообщения

Tags: java, ооп, юнит-тесты

Постановка задания:

> Написать консольное приложение на java, с использованием maven.
>
> Приложение должно выводить на экран приветственное сообщение, в
>   зависимости от текущего времени суток.
>
> Good morning, World! в 06:00 - 09:00 Good day, World! в 09:00 - 19:00
>   Good evening, World! в 19:00 - 23:00 Good night, World! в 23:00 -
>   06:00 ​Код должен содержать все возможные юнит-тесты и создавать
>   читабельный лог файл.
>
> Выводящиеся на консоль сообщения должны быть получены из message
>   resource и зависеть от системной локали пользователя. Сделать перевод
>   на русский язык.

Вопрос: Как исправить ? На граничных значениях неверные сообщения.  Тесты на эти случаи не добавлены. Во всех тестах, также, в assertEquals попутаны местами ожидаемые и реальные значения.

```
public class World {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(World.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Event event = new Event();
        String events = null;
        try{
            events = event.getEvent();
            System.out.println(events);
        }catch (ParseException e){
            log.error("Parse exception",e);
        }
    }
}

public class Event {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Event.class);

    private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    private Date current;//текущий
    private Date morning;//утро
    private Date day;//день
    private Date evening;//вечер
    private Date night;//ночь
    private Date currentDate;//текущая дата
    private String ress;

    public Event(){
        currentDate = new Date();
    }

    public Event(String event) throws ParseException{
        currentDate = dateFormat.parse(event);
    }

    public String  getEvent() throws ParseException{

        Locale.getDefault();
        ResourceBundle res = ResourceBundle.getBundle("message");

        current = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(currentDate));
        morning  = dateFormat.parse(BorderEvent.MORNING.toString());
        day  = dateFormat.parse(BorderEvent.DAY.toString());
        evening = dateFormat.parse(BorderEvent.EVENING.toString());
        night = dateFormat.parse(BorderEvent.NIGHT.toString());

        if(current.after(morning) && current.before(day)){
            ress = res.getString("morning");
            log.info(ress);
            return ress;
        }
        else if (current.after(day) && current.before(evening)){
            ress = res.getString("day");
            log.info(ress);
            return ress;
        }
        else if (current.after(evening) && current.before(night)){
            ress = res.getString("evening");
            log.info(ress);
            return ress;
        }
        else
             ress = res.getString("night");
        log.info(ress);
        return ress;
    }
}

public enum BorderEvent {

    MORNING("06:00:00"),
    DAY("09:00:00"),
    EVENING("19:00:00"),
    NIGHT("23:00:00");

    private final String time;

    BorderEvent(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return time;
    }
}
```

Тесты:

```
public class TestEvent {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestEvent.class);
    private Event event;

    @Test
    public  void testGetEvent() throws ParseException {
        event = new Event();
        log.info(event.getEvent());
        switch (event.getEvent()){
            case "MORNING": break;
            case "DAY": break;
            case "EVENING":break;
            case "NIGHT": break;
            default:
                Assert.fail();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testNightFirst()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("23:00:00");
       // Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "NIGHT");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testNightSecond()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("05:59:59");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "NIGHT");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testNightThree()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("23:00:01");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "NIGHT");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testNightFour()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("02:00:00");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "NIGHT");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMorningFirst()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("06:00:01");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "MORNING");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMorningSecond()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("08:59:59");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "MORNING");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMorningThree()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("07:25:01");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "MORNING");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMorningFour()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("08:00:00");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "MORNING");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }
    @Test
    public void testDayFirst()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("09:00:01");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "DAY");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDaySecond()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("18:59:59");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "DAY");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDayThree()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("15:35:51");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "DAY");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDayFour()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("16:53:15");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "DAY");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEveningFirst()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("19:00:01");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "EVENING");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEveningSecond()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("22:59:59");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "EVENING");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEveningThree()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("21:25:01");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "EVENING");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEveningFour()throws ParseException{
        event = new Event("22:00:00");
        //Assert.assertEquals(event.getEvent(), "EVENING");
        log.info(event.getEvent());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя нету условия того что время равно, есть только больше и меньше. Необходимо его добавить в условия

```
if(current.after(morning) && current.before(day) || current.equal(morning)){
        ress = res.getString("morning");
        log.info(ress);
        return ress;
    }
    else if (current.after(day) && current.before(evening)|| current.equal(day)){
        ress = res.getString("day");
        log.info(ress);
        return ress;
    }
    else if (current.after(evening) && current.before(night)|| current.equal(morning)){
        ress = res.getString("evening");
        log.info(ress);
        return ress;
    }
    else
         ress = res.getString("night");
    log.info(ress);
    return ress;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое ;-)

Comment: @Евгений отметь ответ как верный, если он тебе помог.